# sqlite read pdf file from database

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, pdf

I'm a little stuck with this...
I have a code to insert a PDF file into a blob as bytes:

```vb
Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
With ofd
    .InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath
    .Filter = "PDF Files|*.pdf"
    .FileName = Nothing
    .ShowDialog()
End With
MsgBox(ofd.FileName)

Dim filePath As String = ofd.FileName
Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
Dim br As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(fs)
Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length))

br.Close()
fs.Close()

Dim con As New SQLiteConnection(db)
Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand
Try
    con.Open()
    cmd = con.CreateCommand
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Employee SET File = @File WHERE ID = 20"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
    con.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
End Try
```

This works, but now I need to reverse it and load the PDF file (I don't want to save the PDF back into the computer, all I need is to view it...)
This is what I have to retrieve the PDF file:

```vb
Dim con As New SQLiteConnection(db)
Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand
Dim File As New DataTable

Try
    con.Open()
    cmd = con.CreateCommand
    Dim CommandText As String = "SELECT File FROM Employee WHERE ID = 20"
    Dim adapter As New SQLiteDataAdapter(CommandText, con)
    adapter.Fill(File)

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
    con.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
End Try
```

But it doesn't work...

Anyone have another way to do it?

Comment: Since SQLite is file based, you would be much better off saving the PDFs (images as well) to some archive location and just store that full path name to the DB.  The name can be obfuscated and the row ID can be used to assure a unique name

Comment: ...that said, PDF is not a type known to SQLite so the DataTable wont contain one.  You need to write the bytes to a temp file to view it

Comment: You didn't reverse it - where is your BinaryReader? I would write the binary data to a temp file with pdf extension, and shell execute the file, let Windows decide how to open it.

Comment: You're not opening the pdf anywhere. What are you using to open your pdf? Local installed software or a library like aspose pdf?

Comment: @Plutonix, I know that is the way to go, but I need it not to be saved on the computer as a pdf (per client request).

Comment: @djv, That is the part that I'm having problems with... I can't seem to find how to do it...

Comment: @Chillzy, I can't open the pdf before I reverse it back to pdf... I'm using Acrobat Reader to read the pdf (locally installed), but first I need to reverse the bytes back to pdf...

Comment: but you will still have to create a temporary file on the disk to open it. In your solution you are reading the file to a bit array and store it into your table on column named "file" that contains bytes. When you query your pdf back you need to take the array of bytes stored in your column and write it back to a file then open the file.

Comment: Unless you work out a way for Adobe reader to work off an array of bytes, you **must** create a temp file.

Comment: A temp file is fine. My problem is writing it back into a pdf file... That I don't know how to do...

Comment: the same way you read them with a binarywriter https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I fixed it...

```
    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd = con.CreateCommand
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT File FROM Employee WHERE ID = 20"
        Dim bytes As Byte() = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream("d:\test.pdf", FileMode.Create)
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
        fs.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
        cmd.Dispose()

    End Try
```

Thanks for the help